# Erro ao fazer backup no wpf c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Estou com problema em realizar backup no meu sistema.

Estou usando **WPF** com **SQLSERVER 2008**, nesse sistema preciso realizar o backup dos dados na maquina local do cliente, então to criando o diretório do do backup no Disco `C:\\`.

Porém ele esta me retornando esse erro, andei pesquisando sobre o assunto fala que é permissão, mais já dei permissão tanto no **sqlserver** e na pasta dentro o **IOS**.

segue a imagem do erro e o meu código.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    private void backupSistemaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            if ((!System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\DBBackup")))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\DBBackup");
            }
            string destdir = "C:\\DBBackup\\SISTEMA_CCA" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".bak";
            cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
            cg.con.Open();
            string cb = "backup database [" + Application.StartupPath + "\\SISTEMA_CCA] to disk='" + destdir + "'with init,stats=10";
            cg.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
            cg.cmd.Connection = cg.con;
            cg.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cg.con.Close();
            st1 = LB_Usuario.Text;
            st2 = "Backup realizado com sucesso";
            cf.LogFunc(st1, DateTime.Now, st2);
            MessageBox.Show("Operação concluída com sucesso", "Backup - Banco de dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isso acontece porque a criação do arquivo é delegada ao banco de dados, independentemente de onde o executável está. Ou seja, o SQL Server vai tentar salvar o backup nesta pasta **no servidor do banco de dados**.

Comment: Bom dia Erlon. Cara você poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui resolver o meu problema.
eu estava fornecendo um parametro no lugar do database.

O comando backup possui esse forma

backup database NOME_DA_SUA_BASE to DISK=caminho backup+nome_arq.backup with [options]

entao corrigir essa linha por essa

string cb = "backup database SISTEMA_CCA to disk='" + destdir + "'with init,stats=10";

Problema resolvido !